# Node.Js, express , res.sendFile unable to establish root dir

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple Express server with the following code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var fs = require('fs');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname }))
})


app.listen(9432);
```

Imanage to establish connection ,but when i try to send files i get error saying 
'TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile'
i tried everything i can think of.

server is deploid on http://www.nextweb.rs/

(code runs normaly when tested on localhost)

Comment: `__dirname` is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) incorrectly.

It's a module-scoped global variable, so if you place it in a string (like you're doing) then it won't resolve at all. The string will just be equal to `__dirname`, instead of `/home/ultimate/ultimate` (like you want). This is what it should be:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", { root: __dirname });
});
```

Comment: bad copy paste to Stackoverflow post, i edited, sorry for that, it doesnt work.

Comment: So my code sample doesn't work? What error do you receive?

Comment: "ultimatebug.nextweb.space didn’t send any data."
witch you can check ur self on 
ultimatebug.nextweb.space, after someone visits, it just 'aborts' runing server and thats it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. What error do you receive on the server-side? What gets logged to the console?

Comment: inside websites CLI  i get  'Aborted (core dumped)'
and if i try to specity full path  like 'home/ultimate/ultimate/index.html' where it is actualy located, i get 'res.sendFile unable to establish root dir'

Comment: It's possible that you don't have permission to get the root directory. Please could you run nothing else but `console.log(__dirname)` and comment _exactly_ what the output is?

Comment: [ultimate@ares ultimate]$ node api.js
/home/ultimate/ultimate
[ultimate@ares ultimate]$
 -It gives me '/home/ultimate/ultimate' as root folder, but when i try to set that exact absolute path, its still not working.

Comment: That's so weird. Please could you add a section on to your question that includes this new error?